# how add sharekit action to a tableview cell?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, sharekit

I just added sharekit to my project. Is its action only possible by the use of "share" button in navigationbar? I have a table view and I would like to use the share action by pressing a cell. it is possible (eventually separating differente service in differente cell)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely possible. Checkout `UITableView`'s delegate method for `didSelectRowAtIndex:`. Then in your implementation just call the appropriate share kit service.

```
// Check if the SLComposeViewController is available.
if (NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController")) {

    SLComposeViewController *FBPostSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [FBPostSheet setInitialText:@"I'm posting to Facebook!"];
    [FBPostSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.Apple.com"]];

    [FBPostSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                break;
        }
    }];

    // Apparently its possible for composeViewControllerForServiceType: to return nil... better check.
    if (FBPostSheet) {
        [self presentViewController:FBPostSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Creating Post Sheet");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just have implemented the muy  didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. So I can use directly the shrekit services there? do you know any example of their use? Thanks a lot

Comment: I added an example for Facebook to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Executing youtr method by    [self   yourMethod]; I am experimenting a crash lldb (without anyy more description) just on the first line SLComposeViewController. Have you noticed it?

Comment: maybe Facebook is not available in your country (China?). Check for its availability first ```[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];``` More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205)

Comment: Are you building for iOS6 only? This code won't work on iOS5.

Comment: I wrapped my example in an if statement you can use to see if it was crashing because its unavailable, i.e. iOS5